# Do i still use req.body for json, from Mobile to node.js?

Tags: android, ios, json, node.js, rest

Do i still use req.body if let say, Android or IOS sending the JSON object to node.js server?

For example, the code

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res, next) {
  var movie = new Movie();
  movie.name = req.body.name;
  movie.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.json(movie);
  });
});
```

Comment: `req.body` for **POST** requests, & `req.query` for **GET** requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct.

Provided you used key value pairs or write something like this to an output stream.

```
//Set up the HttpURLConnection
URL url = new URL("http://url.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

//This is where you post the data
writer.write("name=" + movieName);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

You can also send JSON by using:

```
writer.write("movie=" + jsonData.toString());
```